# Is there a neutral word for an olfactory impression?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, sense-verbs, nuance

I was struggling to find the right words for *olfactory impressions*.

Is there a neutral word for an olfactory impression?

- *smell* seems to have a negative connotation
- *aroma* sounds more like having to do with dishes or spices
- *olfactory impression* well, ... that's not a word, it's two. And two that rather focus on the perception of the smell, than on the smell itself.
- *odour*?
- *scent*?

Comment: the term *fragrance* has positive connotations, we speak about a perfume's fragrance, or the fragrances of flowers and if anything is deemed *fragrant*, we tend to think it is pleasant.

Comment: I don't think *smell* is intrinsically negative:  *There were some good smells emanating from the kitchen.*

Comment: Incidentally, apart from positive-negative/ pleasant-unpleasant connotations, each of the words is used in a related context only. They are not interchangeable: A perfume's *aroma; The *scent of fresh bread.

Comment: **Free of context,** *scent* is essentially neutral and universally applicable.

Comment: **It depends on context**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The results in this [Google Books Ngrams chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+smell%2Cthe+odour%2Cthe+odor%2Cthe+scent%2Cthe+fragrance&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20smell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20odour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20odor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20scent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20fragrance%3B%2Cc0) seem to imply that the terms, *the scent* and *the smell* are the most used.

[image]

In order to ascertain how *neutral* these terms were I selected the following criteria.

- smell of *
- scent of *
- smell of the *
- scent of the *
- smells good
- smells bad

The asterisk represents *any word* that follows the last term which Google Books has a record of.

Link to [Ngrams Chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smell%20of%20the%20*%2Csmell%20of%20*%2C%20scent%20of%20*%2C%20scent%20of%20the%20*%2Csmells%20good%2Csmells%20bad&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Csmell%20of%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20earth%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20smoke%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20river%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20flowers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20ocean%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20blood%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20air%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Csmell%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20burning%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20smoke%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20blood%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20fresh%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20death%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cscent%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20flowers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20roses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20pine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20fresh%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20jasmine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cscent%20of%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20flowers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20roses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20rose%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20flower%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20pines%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20earth%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20pine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20forest%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20wild%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmells%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmells%20bad%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Csmell%20of%20the%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20earth%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20food%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20place%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20smoke%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20river%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20flowers%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20ocean%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20blood%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%20air%3B%2Cc1%3B.t2%3B%2Csmell%20of%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20burning%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20smoke%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20blood%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20fresh%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bsmell%20of%20death%3B%2Cc1%3B.t2%3B%2Cscent%20of%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20flowers%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bscent%20of%20roses%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bscent%20of%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20pine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20fresh%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bscent%20of%20jasmine%3B%2Cc1%3B.t2%3B%2Cscent%20of%20the%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20flowers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20roses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20rose%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20flower%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20pines%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20earth%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20pine%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20forest%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bscent%20of%20the%20wild%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmells%20good%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Csmells%20bad%3B%2Cc0)
[image]

---

Judging from the results, it appears that the verb *smell* is more often associated with the adjective *good* than with *bad*, at least in its written form. However, if one notes the different terms used with ***smell of***; *smoke*, *death*, *burning*, and *blood* along with *fresh*, *the sea*, *the earth*, etc. it is clear that both pleasant and unpleasant odours are collocated with *smell*. Whereas the noun scent tends towards positive collocations such as: *roses*, *pine*, *fresh*, *the sea*, *jasmine*, *the flowers*.

Consequently, the OP's choice of **Scents & Smells** for her proposal appears to be a very sensible and objective decision.

Comment: Of course, if _smell_ would have a generally negative connotation, that would explain why "smells bad" is used less, as it could be perceived as a pleonasm, whereas _if_ it is used positively it _has_ to be followed by _good_. I think it is a bit tricky to infer connotations from use like this.

Comment: @oerkelens that's a good point, but how would you check this meaning on Ngram?  I might interpret the following phrase: *"That flower smells"* to mean that the flower has a particularly pungent, perhaps even unpleasant scent. Or I could be commenting on the fact that the other flowers do not have any fragrance whereas this one does!

Comment: Actually, I am quite at a loss as to how to "measure" these kind of connotations, using Ngram or otherwise. My first thought was you had a brilliant idea, and I still think it has its merits, but then I realised there may be too much information that stays invisible. A well set-up double blind test with different groups of native speakers to judge connotations of carefully selected test sentences would do the trick, but I don't have the time to set that up right now... There definitely is a lot going on with the simple word _smell_ :)

Comment: I get the neat explanation, I don't get the conclusion: The OP is asking for a _neutral_ word. How can words '_more often associated with good than with bad_' and '_usually associated with pleasing odours_' be more _neutral_ than others?

Comment: @Mina if you look at the type of words associated with smell: *smell of death*, *smell of burning*, *smell of blood* those expressions prove to me that *smell* is more neutral than *fragrance* for example, because both "good" and "bad" odours are used with *smell*. Instead *scent* tends towards positive collocations which I pointed out in my conclusion.

Comment: I can follow you till the end now. But I think you should use this as a conclusion instead of your current (which frankly misled me).

Comment: @mina I have just edited my conclusion. Thank you for your query, it was most helpful!

Comment: We humans have evolved an olfactory system with significant danger triggers; so most smells that we recognize have meaning, in the sense that developing the ability has contributed to survival; many things smell good, but more smell bad, and the ones we perceive as "strong" are almost universally dangerous in one way or another. If you say _This smells_ without specifying anything else, it means that it stinks. You have to add _good_ to mean _good_; that's why _smells good_ so common in the data.

Comment: Another inference one could make from that graph is that things have been getting smellier since the 70's.

Answer (score 2):

I think  [odour](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odor) ( or scent) is the more general and neutral term, to convey specific olfactory impressions you have to use other definitions such as fragrance, aroma or malodour for instance:

> - is caused by one or more volatilized chemical compounds, generally at a very low concentration, that humans or other animals perceive by the sense of olfaction.
>
>   - Odours are also commonly called *scents, which can refer to both pleasant and unpleasant odors.* *The terms fragrance and aroma are used primarily by the food and cosmetic industry to describe a pleasant odor, and are sometimes used to refer to perfumes.* In contrast, *malodor, stench, reek, and stink* are used specifically to describe unpleasant odor. sometimes the term funk can be used to describe unpleasant odour.

Source: www.wikipedia.org

Comment: But is *odour* neutral? It does usually convey negativity. When used metaphorically I might say for example *but if you do that it will put you in bad odour with the neighbours*. We seldom, if ever, talk about being in *good odour* with anything. We might say instead *that will make us sweet with the people next door*. In the latter case we are using a taste metaphor.

Comment: I think it is, in your example you use the adjective 'bad' to give a connotation to odour. As shown above it may refer either to pleasant or unpleasant scents. I think it is the more general and neutral term in this respect.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good+odor%2Bgood+odour%2Cbad+odor%2Bbad+odour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28good%20odor%20%2B%20good%20odour%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28bad%20odor%20%2B%20bad%20odour%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: compare: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good+scent%2Cbad+scent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgood%20scent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbad%20scent%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Do the Ngrams above show that odour or scent are not 'neutral' terms?

Comment: Yes, they strongly show their collocational bad-friends.

Comment: You need an adjective to give them a positive or negative connotation. Anyway thanks for your opinion. :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the original poster, and some of the commenters.

"Smell" and "odour / odor" both definitely have negative connotations. (If this were not so, "smelly," which is just "smell" with a "y" added, would not be negative while "tasty" is regarded as positive.)

"Scent" has a positive connotation, but also a feminine connotation. I can't see a guy mentioning or describing a "scent" unless he works for the perfume industry. English needs to have a better neutral word for "smell" than "smell," but so far, it doesn't.

Here's an interesting article from The Atlantic on the paucity of words to describe smells, as well: https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2015/11/the-vocabulary-of-smell/414618/

Comment: While new answers to old questions are welcome on this site (unlike many other places on the Internet), they are expected to be posted only when they add something significant to what already appears on the same page (not to express agreement with it). This seems to be more of a comment than an answer (the distinction between the two is an important aspect of the architecture of this site).

Answer (score -1):

OP writes:

> ... struggling to find the right words for *olfactory impressions*.

If you want to refer to the *action* of the olfactory sense, you could use a gerund,  "smelling".

> *Smelling* is a chemical process. When we smell a smell, molecules...

It is a way to refer abstractly to the act or mechanism, which is what you seem to be trying to do, so that there is no connotation of pleasantness or unpleasantness in the word for what is smelled. **SOMETIMES YOU WILL ACTUALLY HAVE TO USE THE LANGUAGE TO ESTABLISH A CONTEXT RATHER THAN WASTING TIME SEARCHING FOR THE ELUSIVE "PERFECT" WORD**.