# What do I 'smell'?

Tags: vocabulary

I *see* images. I *touch* objects.  I *taste* flavours.  I *hear* sounds.

Is there a collective generic noun, besides 'smells', for what I *smell*?

**Edit**:

Example sentence:

> Whenever I smell that ____ I think of France.

Comment: *odours* and *smells*. I think this question has been asked before.

Comment: related: [Is there a neutral word for an olfactory impression?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197046/is-there-a-neutral-word-for-an-olfactory-impression)

Comment: I did look and couldn't find an answer.  'Odours' certainly fits the bill -*the property of a substance that is perceptible by the sense of smell* (OED).  Interestingly, the OED says that 'early' use was usually for 'a sweet or pleasing scent', whereas now odour frequently describes an unpleasant smell.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - great answer.  Thank you! (no wonder you thought it had been asked before!).

Comment: "I smell smells" doesn't sound great though. Maybe someone will come up with an obscure technical term.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes.  That was my starting position.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - which, on reflection, suggests that the most useful, neutral word IS 'smells'.  No shame in that!

Comment: Well, you could always smell a *stink*.  Or a rat.

Comment: Dan, it's important to show us how you want to use the word you're asking us to help you find.  In the list, *I smell **odors/odours*** is good, but in a different context it might be something else.  For example, "I know you've been raiding the cookie jar.  Not from any crumbs on your tie, but from the tell-tale smell of chocolate chips."  And at our house, as a joke, when someone needs a shower, we like to say, "There's an *aroma* that tells me you need a shower."

Comment: @aparente001 - I was wanting the word that would match 'flavour' (for tasting), 'feel' (for touching), 'sound' (for hearing), 'image' (for seeing).

Comment: But Dan, there's more than one word for that.  Could you please give us an example sentence, *to show us how you want to use the word you're asking us to help you find*?

Comment: @aparente001 - *Whenever I smell that ____ I think of France*(!).

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps **scent**:

> noun:
>
> 1. a distinctive odor, especially when agreeable: the scent of roses.
> 2. an odor left in passing, by means of which an animal or person may be traced.
> 3. a track or trail as or as if indicated by such an odor: The dogs lost the scent and the prisoner escaped.
> 4. perfume.
> 5. the sense of smell: a remarkably keen scent.
> 6. small pieces of paper dropped by the hares in the game of hare and hounds.

Reference: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scent

Comment: *Scent* works well with the example sentence: "Whenever I smell that scent, I think of France."  But it might be even nicer to say, "Whenever I notice that scent, I think of France."

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you smell smells or odors/odours. If you need a technical term, you smell *odorants* (which are the actual molecules detected by your olfactory system).

The usual wording is "detect odorants" or "sense odorants", but "smell odorants" is also attested. *Odorant* has the synonyms *aroma-compound* and *odor/odour compound*, but it doesn't seem "smell aroma/odour compounds" is attested.

Comment: But most people will interpret "odorant" to mean an artificial substance, used to intentionally add an odor to something.