# Can the word smell be used for something nice?

Tags: british-english

I ask because I feel the word Smell is to connote something awful and the word scent or aroma for something pleasant.

Comment: Yes, the word "smell" can be used when describing a pleasant odor.

Comment: almost a duplicate of: [Is there a neutral word for an olfactory impression?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197046/is-there-a-neutral-word-for-an-olfactory-impression)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAJQkwmwesY But for some, "the smell of death" is pleasant.

Comment: Connotations change with collocates / wider context. 'There's a smell in here' doubtless connotes a foul smell, but 'There's a smell in here that reminds me of when we used to go for walks in the autumn meadows' doesn't. And as for 'I love the smell of freshly ground coffee' ...

Answer (score 2):

A standard dictionary definition helps you understand what 'tone' or connotation the word carries: the Cambridge Dictionary defines **smell** [noun] UK as

> the characteristic of something that can be recognized or noticed using the nose

The dictionary also gives a number of explanatory examples:

> What's your favourite smell?
>
> I love the smell of orange blossoms.
>
> The marketplace was filled with delightful smells.
>
> There's a delicious smell in here.
>
> I wish we could get rid of that smell (= bad smell) in the bathroom [...]
>
> There was an unpleasant smell coming from the drains.
>
> The delicious smell of freshly-made coffee came from the kitchen.
>
> the smell of decaying meat
>
> What's that horrible smell?

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smell

In short, unlike positively loaded words like [fragrance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fragrance) and [aroma](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aroma), or negatively loaded words like [stench](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stench) and [stink](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stink), the word "smell" by itself has ***neutral*** connotations, and the context in which it is used -- particularly the other nouns or adjectives associated with it -- will provide information to help us decide whether the connotation in the particular situation is good or bad, as demonstrated by these examples.

So the word "smell" can be used for something nasty, and also for something nice!